# How to pass List<Identifier<Foo>> to method with List<Identifier<?>> parameter?

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have a class `Identifier<T>` which essentially is a type-safe wrapper around a UUID (so class `Foo` contains an `Identifier<Foo>`).

The `FooStore` class has a method `List<Identifier<Foo>> bulkReadIdentifiers()`.

In another class, I need to turn this `List<Identifier<Foo>>` into a `List<UUID>`. Implementing a method that does this for `Foo` is trivial, but how do I declare the method so that it works for arbitrary classes, i.e. `Bar` instead of `Foo`?

The method `List<UUID> extractUuids(List<Identifier<?>> identifiers)` causes compile errors because the `?` does not match `Foo`. Can this be solved without using a hack that involves raw lists and/or `@SuppressWarnings`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the method generic:

```
<T> List<UUID> extractUuids(List<Identifier<T>> identifiers)
```